# hibernate.cfg.xml not found (The file actually doesn't exist). Configuration is in dispatcher-servlet

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate.cfg.xml

I have configured hibernate in my dispatcher servlet. The program starts fine. But when creating a `Configuration` object and configuring it by calling the `configure()` method, the error is thrown:

```
    Apr 03, 2013 9:14:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
    INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    Apr 03, 2013 9:14:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
    INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    Error creating session: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    Apr 03, 2013 9:14:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/LibraryTest1] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
    org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1934)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1914)
    at com.csu.library.mvc.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:24)
    at com.csu.library.mvc.dao.generic.GenericHibernateDao.getSession(GenericHibernateDao.java:29)
    at com.csu.library.mvc.dao.implementation.UserDaoImpl.getUserByUsername(UserDaoImpl.java:23)
    at com.csu.library.mvc.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.getUser(UserServiceImpl.java:46)
    at com.csu.library.mvc.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.login(UserServiceImpl.java:57)
    at com.csu.library.mvc.controller.UserController.homepage(UserController.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I get the Configuration object to configure from the dispatcher servlet where the hibernate configuration is defined?

The method that builds the sessionfactory is as follows:

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

static {
    try {
        //Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
    catch(HibernateException he) {
        System.err.println("Error creating session: " + he); 
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
    }
}
```

The dispatcher-servlet code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Scans the package for contents -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.csu.library.mvc"/>

    <!-- Maps static resources like images, css, javascript files -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name = "viewClass" value = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsps/"/>
        <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/csu_library"/>
        <property name="username" value="csulibrary"/>
        <property name="password" value="csulibrary"/>

        <!-- Pool Properties -->
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id = "hibernateProperties" class = "java.util.Properties">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "sessionFactory" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value = "com.csu.library.mvc"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref = "dataSource"/>        
        <property name="hibernateProperties" ref = "hibernateProperties"/>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Please put your applicationContext.xml. I want to see how your are initializing hibernate part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through you have integrated hibernate to spring why do you still use hibernate to build sessionFactory, in other words, you don't have to use hibernate.cfg.xml there is a sessionFactory bean already in the applicationContext.xml, just use annotation to get it's instance. then enjoy it:)

see your another question for my answer
[SessionFactory injection isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809476/sessionfactory-injection-isnt-working/15810281#15810281)

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I scrapped off the method with Configuration object. I tried to make the changes. I have removed 'static' from both the method and variable but still the sessionFactory is null.

Answer (score 0):

root cause is `org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found`. By default Hibernate configuration manager try to find cfg file in `WEB-INF/classes`, put your `hibernate.cfg.xml` in `WEB-INF/classes` foldern and it should work.

Edit::

You are trying to buid session factory by own hence it is just like typical hibernate application. In this case `hibernate.cfg.xml` will be required. But you can see there is `session factory bean` in `application-contex.xml`. When `spring` loads the `xml` then `hibernate.cfg.xml` is not requıred because `session factory` is already defined in `application-context` and it will be created.

Comment: it doesn't exist as i have incorporated the hibernate.cfg.xml code in the dispatcher servlet in the form of beans.

Comment: Can you edit the question and put some code how you are doing initialization

Comment: @nick-s I have added modified answer

Comment: I figured I would have to use HibernateTemplate instead of Session to interact with database which I don't want to do. I have already implemented my system using Session object. I wonder if it is possible to interact with the database bypassing the use of HibernateTemplate.

Comment: You want sessin object from Spring session factory ?

Comment: yeah but the session factory i think isn't being injected to the sessionfactory variable

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. why you need configuration file if you are providing it in dispatcher.

but your accessing session factory is wrong.

"Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();" will always go for

Configuration file. You need to access it by HibernateTamplate which is provided by Spring.

please check following link to solve your error.

http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-and-spring-integration

http://www.javabeat.net/2007/10/integrating-spring-framework-with-hibernate-orm-framework/