# SessionFactory injection isn't working

Tags: java, hibernate, session, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

My SessionFactory isn't being injected to SessionFactory variable. My configuration is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Scans the package for contents -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.csu.library.mvc"/>

    <!-- Maps static resources like images, css, javascript files -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name = "viewClass" value = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsps/"/>
        <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/csu_library"/>
        <property name="username" value="csulibrary"/>
        <property name="password" value="csulibrary"/>

        <!-- Pool Properties -->
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id = "hibernateProperties" class = "java.util.Properties">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "sessionFactory" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value = "com.csu.library.mvc"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref = "dataSource"/>        
        <property name="hibernateProperties" ref = "hibernateProperties"/>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**HibernateUtil.class**

```
package com.csu.library.mvc.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateUtil {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(getSessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }
}
```

The program throws **NullPointerException** when getSessionFactory() method is called. Obviously, sessionFactory isn't being injected. The program starts up fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: And you are sure your Util class is in the directory com.csu.library.mvc ?

Comment: I think so. The package name of the Util class is com.csu.library.mvc.hibernate

Comment: How is the Util class bean is created in your project?

Comment: @code13 I have added the HibernateUtil class which has the SessionFactory variable that gets SessionFactory object via injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inject like following, it'll work fine

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

Hope to help you:)

Comment: Still throws NullPointerException

Comment: please look at my code carefully, the variable of SessionFactory is not static. then do you realize how to do?

Comment: I tried to make the changes. I have removed 'static' from both the method and variable but still the sessionFactory is null.
Please see the updated HibernateUtil class.

Comment: how do you use HibernateUtil class to get the hibernate session factory? new Instance or via autowiring?

Comment: I have tried just now by @Autowired private HibernateUtil util; through this way can get the instance.

Comment: and don't forget to add @Component at HibernateUtil class :)

Answer (score 0):

In some Spring versions, sub folders are not scanned. 
Either move your class in the package com.csu.library.mvc or add the package com.csu.library.mvc.hibernate in the scanned packages and give it a try.

Comment: Both adding a packege and moving class failed?

Comment: I added the aforementioned package to the base-package attribute. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired` annotation instead of `javax.inject.Inject`.

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that  only looks for annotations on beans in the same
application context it is defined in. This means that, if you put  in
a WebApplicationContext for a DispatcherServlet, it only checks for @Autowired beans in your
***controllers***, and not your services.